# Rails 5 - Unpermitted params with multi select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following worker model which accepts nested attributes for services.

**worker.rb**

```
class Worker < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :services, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services
end
```

**service.rb**

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :worker, optional: true
end
```

A service has a single attribute 'name' being the name of the service.

I've whitelisted the name attribute in worker strong params.

```
def worker_params
  params.require(:worker).permit(
    :first_name, :last_name, services_attributes: [:name, :_destroy])
end
```

In my form, I'm using a multi select nested field for name.

[Form multi input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW2WN.png)

A user should be able to select the services that they offer using this field, which then creates the services. In the case of the screenshot, 3 services should be created.

When I submit the form, I'm getting `unpermitted parameter: name`. Params are below;

```
Parameters:{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"wpxjde/exG29soyCA7kEaceeKZSxShcFjpD6gjG
1GF2Yg3mAdfMd4UJQi3tTHOeS/XOas9aMIjUiRriDxJZKrg==", "worker"=>
{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "services_attributes"=>{"0"=>
{"name"=>["", "Cleaning", "Organising", "Washing"], 
"_destroy"=>"false"}}}, 
"commit"=>"Create worker"}
```

How can I accept the selections made by the user, and create a service object for each?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

**Worker controller**

```
  def new
    @worker = Worker.new
    @worker.services.build
  end

  def create
    @worker = Worker.create(worker_params)
    if @worker.save
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Please check the errors below"
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**View form fields**

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :services do |service| %>
<tr class="nested-fields">
  <td><%= f.input :name, label: false, class: 'form-control', as: :select, collection: services_helper, input_html: { multiple: true, class: 'service-dropdown' } %></td>
  <td><%= link_to_remove_association "remove service", f, class: 'btn btn-danger' %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You are want to use `multiselect` input for _a single attribute 'name'_ ? Don't you think it's contradiction? Use an array where you can use only a string? Remove `multiple: true` from name select.

Comment: I want to create multiple service records which have a name attribute by entering a number of names in one field.